# Android TouchImageView Scale Type Center Crop

Tags: android, image, touchimageview

Im using the TouchImageView with scale type patch but when i try to use the method

getOriginalZoomedImageSource()

the image does not match up to the preview

does anyone know might be wrong or have a working version when using scale type centre crop

https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/commit/475b552b468c1da10d6802cefaa00cf5e39b27d1

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by taking into account the zoom amount, by multipling the left, right width and height by the zoom amount, which you can get by using the getCurrentZoom method, produces a image which matches the preview when using centre crop as a scale type, not tested on any other cale types